# Using trained Scikit-learn svm classifiers in Android

Tags: android, scikit-learn

I am developing an Android app that uses sensor data from the phone to classify activities. I also really prefer scikit-learn to any of the Java machine learning  libraries. So I created a very minimal REST api using Django and scikit learn to train sensor data using support vector machines and return model information.

My question is this: how can I use the model scikit-learn produces on my phone to make predictions? So far I've considered extending the api so that whenever the phone wants to make a prediction, it sends the data to the api to get one. But I'd much rather be able to write some Java code or use a Java library to do the predicting. Sending data for training to the api isn't a problem, for that's not done in real time --- it's only done when the data has already been collected. Sending data for real-time predictions doesn't seem workable, however.

Doing this with logistic regression is a lot easier as the prediction formula and model parameters are pretty simple; I could abandon svms and use this instead, but I'd also like to have svms available.

Anyone aware of someone doing this before? Is there a doable-in-a-relatively-short-time-by-someone-without-a-PhD-in-numerical-computing-or-machine-learning way to do this? Detailed steps aren't necessary, just an outline of how to use the components of the svm that scikit-learn produces.

Comment: I assume you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625359/support-vector-machine-for-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of packages with SVM (scikit-learn too) rely on libsvm implementation. But you don't need 99% of code from libsvm and you don't have to be PhD, because you already have all parameters after learning inside scikit-learn. All what you need - any simple linear algebra library (only for vector*vector operation) in java to implement a decision function.

If you are using linear kernel in SVC - it's relatively easy, because scikit-learn automatically converts all those complicated dual coefficients and support vectors into simple hyperplane coefficients, thus decision function becomes equivalent to logistic regression, all what you need here - dot product - look here [Exporting SVM classifiers from sklearn to Java codebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424160/exporting-svm-classifiers-from-sklearn-to-java-codebase)

In case with non-linear kernel - again only decision function is needed, but now you have to understand what is support vectors, what is dual coefficients, what is kernel, and you have to implement your non-linear kernel in java. I think that it's not easy task to implement decision function for non-linear SVC without understanding how SVC optimization process works, i'll give you some links:

1. [Layout of SVC attributes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#multi-class-classification)
2. [Decision Function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc)
3. [Where all these dual coefficients and support vectors come from](https://youtu.be/eHsErlPJWUU?list=PLCA2C1469EA777F9A)

Or you can just find any SVM library for java and learn model with same parameters you choose in SVC (C, eps, etc). I think it's easiest solution for non-linear kernels. SVM is well-known method, and i think that learning with same parameters and dataset will give same results on any good implementation (besides that most of implementations and bindings, as i said, rely on libsvm, in this case equality is guaranteed).