# how to use ML Models in android application

Tags: android, android-studio, machine-learning, data-mining, prediction

my graduation project is about android application using data mining techniques or ML models to predict Covid-19 from datasets (not APIs) , there will be a part for the user to search by region to know whether this region is safe or crowded with covid cases with a statistics to avoid going there, and the other part is a chatbot which takes user symptoms and predict whether this symptoms are Covid-19 or just a flu.
The problem is that i was a web developer and i didn't use android studio before, and i never used ML and i don't know how to start in this project, can any one guide me how to start and give me some guidelines please? It is for a graduation project purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for specific programming questions. Whole projects is too broad. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/295004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Create Android Application

If you don't have experience using Android Studio, don't worry, it is really easy. You should start with the "Create your first App" tutorial in the web of Android Developers.

- https://developer.android.com/guide

You can write your applications using Java and Kotlin. I recommend you to use Java since most tutorials of using ML in Android use Java.

## Create a ML classifier that can be used in Android

Since you haven't specified the ML algorithms that you have to use, I'll give you two options.

### SVM (Support Vector Machines)

The first option is to use an SVM (Support Vector Machine). This is an easy way of generating a classificator (in your case, you have to classify sets of symptoms between COVID-19 and Flu). Here is a tutorial on using SVM:

- [SVM Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/svm-classification-scikit-learn-python)

Once you have trained the SVM, you have to export it for using in Java. Here is an explanation on how to do that:

- [Using trained Scikit-learn svm classifiers in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535103/using-trained-scikit-learn-svm-classifiers-in-android)

### Neural Networks

The second option is to use a Neural Network. If you choose this option, I recommend you to take at least the first course of the Deep Learning Specialization in Coursera by Andrew Ng. If you don't want to pay it, you can audit the course and see the videos for free:

- [Deep Learning Specialization - Courses](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning#courses)

In this course, you'll learn to create a neural network and to train it using Keras in Python. after you have trained the neural network, you can export the generated model and convert it to tflite format (Tensorflow Lite).

- [Convert Keras Model into tfLite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#convert_a_keras_model_)

This model can then be used in Android.

- [Use tfLite model in Android](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's really helpful and I appreciate it, but excuse me can i ask you another question? .. About the another part of the application which is search for covid by region which shows a statistics of this region is safe or crowded with cases, how could i make this part because i don't have any idea.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend using an API for obtaining the most updated information. The part of the application that tells if a region is safe does not need a machine learning approach, so you could just use information from an API. The WHO has an API for this: https://www.who.int/emergencies/diseases/novel-coronavirus-2019/phsm

Comment: On the other hand, for training the models, you need a dataset with labeled examples of covid and flu cases. I recommend you to take a look at kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/tags/covid19

Comment: Unfortunately my supervisor wants me to not use any APIs and only build a model and train it on a dataset, do you have ideas how should i start in this part, or what should i learn?

Comment: In that case, you can just download from the API the most updated data, and just use it as your dataset. If have any further question, you can find how to contact me in my profile.

If you liked my answer, please, mark it as accepted and up-vote it.

Comment: yes, it was very useful, I will, thank you!